# CMakeLists.txt add subfolder which represents namespace (just for organization)

Tags: c++, cmake

Consider the following setup:

```
-project
--src
---CMakeLists.txt
---main.cpp
---Application.cpp
---Application.hpp
---subfolder
----SomeClass.cpp
----SomeClass.hpp
--bin
```

And consider this `CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(SampleProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Include directories
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("subfolder")

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Now, as long as I had all my classes in the same folder (`src`) everything worked perfectly fine.

But now I want to restructure my application a bit. I want to build a folder-hierarchy that represents the namespaces.

Of course in my includes I would then use

```
#include "subfolder/SomeClass.hpp"
```

but it doesn't work that way. I had a look at the manpage but there are so many options in CMake and it's often talking about standalone libraries that have their own CMakeLists.txt... I'm not that far yet. I just want to add a subfolder, that's all.

Until now I've used QMake for my C++ projects, but I wanted to dive into CMake now.

Are there any useful tutorials out there? I've found a few, but they they don't cover the basics.

Comment: `Are there any useful tutorials out there?` - Care, such questions attracts Close Votes for "requesting tools, libraries and other tutorials" reason. Actually, I don't quite undestand your problem. If you want some headers hierarchy, just create it somewhere under the source dir, and mark root of this hierarchy (`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` in your case) by `include_directories()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommened way is to use a `CMakeLists.txt` for every subdirectory in existence. If you want to have subdirectories and organize them without having to create multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files, you can create one in the main directory with those contents:

```
project(SampleProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include_directories(src)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_LIST *.c* *.h*)

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Comment: Really? Adding all the files manually? Seems kind of tedious. I mean, if you have a really small project, ya, fine, but bigger ones?

Comment: What do you mean with manually? ```file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_LIST *.c* *.h*)``` searches for all the filles with the *.c* and *.h* patterns automatically when cmake runs over the path.

Comment: I mean like when you have a CMakeLists.txt for each subfolder, wouldn't you also specify all files manually? What's the point in having multiple CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: The point is related to project management, because for every subdirectory you could have different build rules or even decide whether you prefer libraries (shared, static) at some parts of your project or tell the compiler use other flags for those files. If you just want  to build the files, there is not point.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`aux_source_directory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/aux_source_directory.html) is used mainly for template related things. Also it's common practice to use a toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`, which includes the further files, has common project settings etc.:

```
<project>
|
+- CMakeLists.txt
|
+- src/
   |
   +-- CMakeLists.txt
   |
   +-- main.cpp
   |
   …
```

So this would look like:

#### CMakeLists.txt (Project dir):

```
project(SampleProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include_directories(src) # Add 'src' to include paths
subdirs(src) # Includes the 'src' directory and its cmake file

# ...
```

Now you can use the include path as expected.

#### CMakeLists.txt (src dir):

```
# Better add src files this way:
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp Application.cpp)

subdirs(subfolder) # TODO: handle subfolder
```

The subfolder can be added through an additional library target, that is linked to your executable. Usually there's another CMakeLists.txt file in there.

---

Also make sure your cmake cache is updated; best you recreate it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, as the `subfolder` would then need another `CMakeLists.txt` I don't want to manage dozens of these, I just want to use folders for organization, so I don't have to dig through hundreds of files in one folder.

Comment: How? (that's the whole point) I want to have a hierarchy and add subfolders to the build.