# CMake: Setting up namespaced includes

Tags: cmake

#### Directory structure

```
-project (XYZ)
--include
---library.h
---module_1.h
---module_2.h
--src
---library.cc
---module_1.cc
---module_2.cc
--CMakeLists.txt
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(XYZ)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(XYZ SHARED library.cc module_1.cc module_2.cc)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

I want to reference module_1 from module_2 like

```
#include <XYZ/module_2.h>
```

I read this post [CMakeLists.txt add subfolder which represents namespace (just for organization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693867/cmakelists-txt-add-subfolder-which-represents-namespace-just-for-organization/34695106#34695106). But the answer is not of much use to me.

It will be more better if there exists a way to do that without making changes to directory structure.

Comment: `there exists a way to do that without making changes to directory structure.` - No, there is no such way. The same I commented for the referenced question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is actually to change the directory structure, but only of your include directory.

So instead of

```
-project (XYZ)
--include
---library.h
---module_1.h
---module_2.h
--src
---library.cc
---module_1.cc
---module_2.cc
--CMakeLists.txt
```

You could do:

```
-project (XYZ)
--include
---XYZ
----library.h
----module_1.h
----module_2.h
--src
---library.cc
---module_1.cc
---module_2.cc
--CMakeLists.txt
```

Then, instead of using `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` use instead:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include 
    PRIVATE 
      src)
```